# Laravel 5.5 error messages

Tags: laravel

после php artisan make:auth сообщения о ошибках в Login и Register имеют след. вид [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как можно исправить???

Comment: Проверьте  есть ли у вас такой файл `\resources\lang\en\validation.php`

Comment: да есть такой файл

Answer (score 0):

Вы не указали какой язык указан у вас в приложении, если указан не стандартный язык, для него нужно указать файлы локализации, эти файлы лежат в папке `resources/lang/xx`, взять файлы локализации можно с библиотеки [Laravel-lang](https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang).

Просто можно скачать репозиторий и скопировать нужную папку в `resources/lang`.

Comment: хотелось бы чтобы сообщения были на английском

Comment: А локаль какая в конфиге указана? Видимо не английская

Comment: 'locale' => 'en',